# Consulta sobre Phpmailer y vinculacion con cuenta de Gmail

Tags: php, php5, phpmailer, gmail

Estoy queriendo asociar una cuenta de gmail con Php mailer pero no estoy teniendo respuesta a la hora de recibir datos de un formulario. La pagina que estoy haciendo [es la siguiente](http://bric.com.ar/ws/) y el archivo q estoy haciendo es el que adjunto abajo. Lo que no se si hay q tener en cuenta algo para generar el PHP con gmail.

```js
<?php
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_STRICT);
date_default_timezone_set('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires');

if ((isset($_POST['ecommerce']) && $_POST['ecommerce'] != "") &&
 (isset($_POST['nombre']) && $_POST['nombre'] != "") &&
 (isset($_POST['telefono']) && $_POST['telefono']!= "" ) &&
 (isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email']!= "") &&
 (isset($_POST['envio']) && $_POST['envio'] === 'envio')  ){

 
 require_once('mailer/class.phpmailer.php');


 
 $emailCliente = "xxxx@gmail.com";
 $passwordCliente = "xxx17";

    
 $fromCliente = $emailCliente;


 $ecommerce = $_POST["ecommerce"];
 $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
 $telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
 $email = $_POST["email"];
 $envio =  $_POST['envio'];
 $address = $email;

 $body  = 
 "
 Datos enviados por el usuario desde el Formulario de contacto: <br/> 
 
 <strong>Ecommerce:</strong> $ecommerce <br/>
 <strong>Nombre y Apellido:</strong> $nombre <br/>
 <strong>Teléfono:</strong> $telefono <br/>
 <strong>Email:</strong> $email <br/>

 "; 
 
 $mail = new PHPMailer();
 $mail->IsSMTP();
 $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
 $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // saber que tipo de cuenta.
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
 $mail->SMTPAuth= true;
 $mail->Port = 465;
 $mail->Username= $emailCliente; // su cuenta de correo
 $mail->Password= $passwordCliente; // su contraseña 
 $mail->From = $emailCliente; // su cuenta
 $mail->FromName= "Welivery";
 $mail->isHTML(true);
 $mail->Subject ="Mensaje de Welivery";
 $mail->Body = $body;

 $mail->addAddress($address, $nombre);

 if (!$mail->send()) {
     $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Error - Comuniquese con el Administrador de la pagina '));
     die($output);
 } else {
     $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'message', 'text' => 'Tu mensaje se ha enviado correctamente. A la brevedad nos contactaremos. Muchas gracias'));
     die($output);
 }

} else {
    $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'message', 'text' =>'No se pudo enviar el email, asegurese que el email exista!!!'));
    die($output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto debería ser un comentario pero no tengo reputación suficiente.

Que versión de PHPMailer estas utilizando??

Haz un print_r o var_dump sobre $mail->send() para ver el error.

---

A mi con esta configuración me funcionaba bien (con gmail). Insisto en que no se que versión de PHPMailer estás utilizando, pero en cualquier caso, si no tienes la última versión, sería recomendable que la utilices.

```
        require('PHPMailer_v5.1/class.phpmailer.php');
        $mail = new phpmailer(true);

        try{
            $mail->Mailer = 'smtp';
            $mail->Host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
            $mail->Port = '465';
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
            $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
            $mail->Username = '...';
            $mail->Password = '...';
            $mail->From = '...';
            $mail->FromName = '...';
            $mail->Timeout = 20;
            $mail->AddAddress("...");
            $mail->Subject = '...';
        }
        catch (phpmailerException $e){
            $err = $e->errorMessage();
            die(print_r($error));
           //si suelta un error, recogelo en un log de errores o mira en el  log de errores de apache o php, aunque con ese die ya lo veras.
        }
```

Respecto al asunto del user y pass, aunque lo ideal sería que el cliente utlice el suyo, a no ser que el volumen de emails sea muy alto, no creo que importe demasiado que pongas otro. Al fin y al cabo, es solo una cuenta de gmail. Create una (que no sea la tuya) y listo.

Comment: Ok voy a probar eso que me decis, pero en cuanto armado de datos para vincular con una cuenta de gmail estara bien?

Comment: @MarianoAndresFranco, sí, te lo digo un poco de memoria, pero yo al menos no he visto nada raro.

Comment: Hola cooper sabes que no pude hacerlo anda, no puedo darme cuenta en que estoy fallando, Si realmente estoy trayendo bien los datos de phpmailer para Gmail, por otro lado las pruebas las quiero hacer con mi cuenta de gmail y viste que en una parte del php hay q poner usuario y contraseña y como este trabajo lo tengo que derivar al cliente yo no se si el cliente va a aceptar de querer poner su user y pass, hay alguna forma de evitar eso? para el uso de php mailer

Comment: @MarianoAndresFranco He editado mi respuesta, a ver si con eso lo puedes solucionar.

Comment: Gracias Cooper, si el cliente medio que no quiere poner sus datos de usuario y contraseña y por otro lado como puedo saber la version de phpmailer que uso? puede pasar que con alguna cuentas de gmail funcione y contras no? porque me genere una cuenta provisoria y me anda pero con dos cuentas mias no funciona.

Comment: ahi agregue una respuesta con lo ultimo que fui haciendo.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_STRICT);
date_default_timezone_set('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires');

if ((isset($_POST['ecommerce']) && $_POST['ecommerce'] != "") &&
 (isset($_POST['nombre']) && $_POST['nombre'] != "") &&
 (isset($_POST['telefono']) && $_POST['telefono']!= "" ) &&
 (isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email']!= "") &&
 (isset($_POST['envio']) && $_POST['envio'] === 'envio')  ){

 
 require_once('mailer/class.phpmailer.php');


 //MAtest2018.01@gmail   MAtest201801!
 $emailCliente = "xxx@gmail.com";
 $passwordCliente = "xxxx";

// $emailCliente = "xxxx@gmail.com"; // su cuenta de correo
// $passwordCliente =  "xxx"; // su contraseña 
 
 $fromCliente = $emailCliente;


 $ecommerce = $_POST["ecommerce"];
 $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
 $telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
 $email = $_POST["email"];
 $envio =  $_POST['envio'];
 $address = $email;

 $body  = 
 "
 Datos enviados por el usuario desde el Formulario de contacto: <br/> 
 
 <strong>Ecommerce:</strong> $ecommerce <br/>
 <strong>Nombre y Apellido:</strong> $nombre <br/>
 <strong>Teléfono:</strong> $telefono <br/>
 <strong>Email:</strong> $email <br/>

 "; 
 
 $mail = new PHPMailer();
 $mail->IsSMTP();
 $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
 $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // saber que tipo de cuenta.
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
 $mail->SMTPAuth= true;
 $mail->Port = 587;
 $mail->Username= $emailCliente; // su cuenta de correo
 $mail->Password= $passwordCliente; // su contraseña 
 $mail->From = $emailCliente; // su cuenta
 $mail->FromName= "Welivery";
 $mail->isHTML(true);
 $mail->Subject ="Mensaje de Welivery";
 $mail->Body = $body;

 $mail->addAddress("electricmarianf@gmail.com", $nombre);

 if (!$mail->send()) {
     $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Error - Comuniquese con el Administrador de la pagina '));
     die($output);
 } else {
     $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'message', 'text' => 'Tu mensaje se ha enviado correctamente. A la brevedad nos contactaremos. Muchas gracias'));
     die($output);
 }

 /*
 $ecommerce = $_POST["ecommerce"];
 $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
 $telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
 $email = $_POST["email"];
 $envio = $_POST['envio'];


 $body  = 
 "
 En brevedad nos estaremos comunicando.

 Muchas Gracias!

 "; 
 
 $mail = new PHPMailer();
 $mail->IsSMTP();
 $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
 $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // saber que tipo de cuenta.
 $mail->SMTPAuth= true;
 $mail->Port = 587;
 $mail->Username= "heyimariano@gmail.com"; // su cuenta de correo
 $mail->Password= "marianoandres"; // su contraseña 
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
 $mail->From = "heyimariano@gmail.com"; // su cuenta
 $mail->FromName= "Welivery";
 $mail->isHTML(true);
 $mail->Subject ="Mensaje de Welivery";
 $mail->Body =$body;

 // $address = $email; // 
 $mail->addAddress($email);

 if (!$mail->send()) {
     $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Error - Comuniquese con el Administrador de la pagina '));
     die($output);
 } else {
     $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'message', 'text' => 'Tu mensaje se ha enviado correctamente. A la brevedad nos contactaremos. Muchas gracias'));
     die($output);
 }*/



} else {
    $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'message', 'text' =>'No se pudo enviar el email, asegurese que el email exista!!!'));
    die($output);
}
```